meson doens't generate import library on windows
i'm having an interesting issue arising using meson-buildsystem on Windows.
i have this simple project setup:
root
 - src
   - game.cpp
   - engine.cpp
 - include
   - engine.h
 - meson.build

with the contents of meson.build being this bare-bones setup:
project('dll_test', 'cpp')

srcdir = 'src'

sources = files('src/engine.cpp')

incdir = include_directories('include')

lib = shared_library('engine',
               sources,
               include_directories : incdir,
               install : true)

executable('game', 'src/game.cpp',
             include_directories : incdir,
             link_with : lib,
             install : false)

the shared_library shouldn't simply generate a dll file but also generate an import library for the executable to link against. however, it never generates said import library, and it results in an error when trying to compile:
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'engine.lib'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.


Does meson generate some files which has the compilation commands, and link flags? Maybe you can inspect them to see if right options are being passed, check for paths, names, etc.
